# How to do this navigation bar and border?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem currently I am converting a psd to HTML
it's a gradient border and around the navigation bar a soft layer of black background
but I did it wrong.

Here's my HTML

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul class="navigation">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS

```
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    height:70px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #151515; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #151515 0%, #151515 37%, #151515 47%, #1a1a1a 61%, #222222 73%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#151515), color-stop(37%,#151515), color-stop(47%,#151515), color-stop(61%,#1a1a1a), color-stop(73%,#222222)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #151515 0%,#151515 37%,#151515 47%,#1a1a1a 61%,#222222 73%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #151515 0%,#151515 37%,#151515 47%,#1a1a1a 61%,#222222 73%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #151515 0%,#151515 37%,#151515 47%,#1a1a1a 61%,#222222 73%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #151515 0%,#151515 37%,#151515 47%,#1a1a1a 61%,#222222 73%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#151515', endColorstr='#222222',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc;
}

#nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

#nav li {
    float: left;
}

#nav li a {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#FFF;
}

ul.navigation {
    background-color:#000;
    width:200px;
    height:30px;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pn8wD/1/). Please stretch the viewing pane so that you can see the result clearly

I want the same color of the psd and its black, but applying my black makes it so dark.

Comment: Why don't you post a picture of the psd so we know exactly what you're talking about?

Comment: oh i thought i did am so sorry here you go http://prntscr.com/2onl4h

Answer (score 0):

Remove the black from the nav and let the gradient show through!

```
background: transparent
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pn8wD/7/

Comment: i checked my fiddle but it doesnt give me the soft black background i wanted